# using statements and Streams

Tags: c#-4.0, stream, using, memorystream

I'm really confused as to what's going on below.  If I just try and return the MemoryStream that is created in the using statement it doesn't work.  However, if I call ToArray and create another stream it works great.  I have alo tried taking the first MemoryStream out of the using statement but the result is the same.

```
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                using (JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
                {
                    JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    jsonSerializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
                    jsonSerializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                    jsonSerializer.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                    jsonSerializer.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
                    jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, account);

                    streamWriter.Flush();
                }
            }

            // Works
            return new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray());
            // Doesn't work
            return memoryStream;
        }
```

Comment: Incidentally, you can 'stack' consecutive 'using' statements; just the bottom one needs an opening brace. Makes your code a lot less indenty (yes that's a word in my world).

Comment: Yes I'm aware but our coding standards don't allow for it.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `using` disposes the stream.
2. It appears that StreamWriter.Dispose() disposes underlying stream. So either find any alternative to StreamWriter that doesn't or make a copy like you did.

Answer (score 0):

"using" does an implicit .Dispose() when it closes, so I'd expect that to not play well with what you're trying to.

I would expect that not using the "using" for the memoryStream would indeed work, curious why that didn't work for you.